# When I dequeue in my Circular Array Queue my items don't display properly

Tags: java, queue

In my Circular Array Queue there are a few parts not finished but ive made it far enough to where my main methods can function. However, for some reason when I use my dequeue function it seems to work properly in retrieving the front but than when displaying my queue again all my items do not display but the queue can still retrieve the front and iterate to the next item.

I've tried looking online at other dequeue methods to see where i may be going wrong but to no avail as they all look similar to my method. I checked if it had to do with setting my queue[frontIndex] equal to null but when i set it equal to the next variable it does not delete the previous item and does not display properly
IE:
1-2-3-4-5
(after dequeue)
2-2-3-4-5

These are my varaibles as well as my dequeue method

```
private T[] queue; //Circular array of queue entries and one unused element 
private int frontIndex;
private int backIndex;
private boolean integrityOK;
private static final int DEFUALT_CAPACITY = 50;
private static final int MAX_CAPACITY = 10000;

    /////////////////////////THE ISSUE///////////////////
@Override
public T dequeue() {

    //Start of if
    if(isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Queue is empty");
    }//End of if

    //retrieve front than delete it
    T front = queue[frontIndex]; 
    queue[frontIndex] = null; 
    frontIndex = (frontIndex + 1) % queue.length; 
    return front;


}
    /////////////////THE ISSUE///////////////////
```

this is also my toString Method

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int temp = 0;
    sb.append("queue: ( ");
    if(queue.length == 0) {
        sb.append("empty queue");
    }
    while(queue[temp]!=null) {
        sb.append(queue[temp].toString());
        sb.append("--->");
        temp++;
    }
    sb.append(")");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

this is the method im testing in my main class

```
public static void testIntegers() {
    System.out.println("\n\nTesting with some integers");

    ArrayQueue<Integer> myIntegerQueue = new ArrayQueue<>();

    int testSet[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for (int i = 0; i < testSet.length; i++) {
        myIntegerQueue.enqueue(testSet[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(myIntegerQueue);

    for (int i = 0; i < testSet.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Dequeue " + myIntegerQueue.getFront());
        myIntegerQueue.dequeue();
        // System.out.println("Dequeue " + myIntegerQueue.dequeue());
        System.out.println(myIntegerQueue);
    }

    // What happens if we try to dequeue from an empty queue?
    System.out.println("Dequeue " + myIntegerQueue.getFront());
    myIntegerQueue.dequeue();
    System.out.println(myIntegerQueue);
}
```

This is what it displays

```
  Testing with some integers
  queue: ( 1--->2--->3--->4--->5--->)
  Dequeue 1
  queue: ( )
  Dequeue 2
  queue: ( )
  Dequeue 3
  queue: ( )
  Dequeue 4
  queue: ( )
  Dequeue 5
  queue: ( )
  Queue is empty
  Dequeue null
  Queue is empty
  queue: ( )
```

after first dequeue expected result

queue: ( 2--->3--->4--->5--->)

actual result

queue: ( )

can someone please inform me or direct me in the right direction as to what im doing wrong cause im at a loss. thank you in advance!

Comment: The problem is this line in your `toString` method:  `int temp = 0;`  Change that to `int temp = frontIndex;`.  And make sure to use modular arithmetic when incrementing `temp`, too, since your queue can wrap around back to 0;

Answer (score 0):

In your `toString()` method you set `temp=0`, then in the while loop you have the condition `while(queue[temp]!=null)`, which means this loop is looking at the very start of the array `queue` and checking if it's `null`, rather than the first element which is indexed by `frontIndex`. When you dequeue the first time, you're setting the first index in the array to be `null`, which then causes the `while` loop in your `toString()` method to not even run due to the condition `while(queue[temp]!=null)`.
Instead of setting `temp=0`, set it as `temp=frontIndex` and this should print your queue as expected.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int temp = frontIndex;
    sb.append("queue: ( ");
    if(queue.length == 0) {
        sb.append("empty queue");
    }
    while(queue[temp]!=null) {
        sb.append(queue[temp].toString());
        sb.append("--->");
        temp++;
    }
    sb.append(")");
    return sb.toString();
}
```